# Viterbi algorithm implementation in C

Tags: c, bioinformatics, markov-chain

This is an implementation of the viterbi algorithm in C, following from Durbin et. al.'s book Biological Sequence Analysis (2002). There's more info in the heading about usage and what exactle the program does.

It's working well and there are no memory leaks, but I'm interested in how I could structure the code better and perhaps make it run faster. I don't know much about good style in C yet. For one, I imagine there's too much in my main() function and I should break it down in to smaller functions, but I'm wondering the best way to do this.

I'm also interested in a better way to read in files, since I've heard that fscanf is risky and error prone. Any other error handling I'm missing as well?

If you want to compile and run the book example, there are the corresponding text files here: [text files](https://github.com/dmmcgee/sequence_analysis_hmm/tree/master/C_implementation/durbin_example)

```
/**
 * Implementation of the viterbi algorithm for estimating the states of a Hidden Markov Model given at least a sequence text file.
 * Program automatically determines n value from sequence file and assumes that state file has same n value.
 * 
 * Program follows example from Durbin et. al.'s "The occasionally dishonest casino, part 1." on p. 54 of Biological Sequence
 * Analyis (2002), with solution and viterbi output given on p. 57. The two states, F and L, correspond to a "Fair" or a "Loaded" die.
 * 
 * free .pdf of Durbin at: http://dnapunctuation.org/~poptsova/course/Durbin-Et-Al-Biological-Sequence-Analysis-CUP-2002-No-OCR.pdf
 * 
 * Optional argument to read in file of known states for comparison with algorithm's output. 
 * Sequence file and state files are is assumed to be one entry per line (see .txt files for example).
 * 
 * Usage: ./viterbi my_sequence_file.txt my_state_file.txt
 * my_sequence_file.txt = sequence file (required)
 * my_state_file.txt = state file (optional)
 *
**/


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>

double max (double a, double b);
int argmax (double row0, double row1);

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    // check for correct number of command line args
    if (argc != 2 && argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./viterbi my_sequence_file.txt my_state_file.txt .  Include at least sequence file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // open sequence file and store in array. Dynamically allocate memory and automatically detect sequence n value
    FILE *seqf = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!seqf)
    {
        printf("Invalid sequence file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int num;
    int memsize = 100;
    int n = 0;
    int *seq = calloc(memsize, sizeof(int));

    while(fscanf(seqf, "%i", &num) == 1)
    {
        seq[n] = num - 1;
        n++;

        if (n == memsize)
        {
            memsize += 100;
            seq = realloc(seq, memsize * sizeof(int));
        }

        if(!seq)
        {
            printf("Not enough memory.");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    fclose(seqf);

    // if passed as an argument, open the state solution file and print. Assumes n is same as sequence n above
    if(argv[2])
    {
        FILE *statef = fopen(argv[2], "r");

        if (!statef)
        {
            printf("Invalid state file.\n");
            return 1;
        }

        char *state = calloc(n, sizeof(char));
        if(!state)
        {
            printf("Not enough memory.");
            return 1;
        }

        char ch;
        printf("State solution:\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            fscanf(statef, "%c %*[\r\n]", &ch);
            state[i] = ch;

            if (i % 60 == 0 && i != 0)
            {
                printf("\n");
            }
            printf("%c", state[i]);
        }
        fclose(statef);
        free(state);
        printf("\n\n");
    }

    // state transition matrix in log space
    double a[2][2] = {
        { log(0.95),  log(0.05) },
        { log(0.1),  log(0.9) }
    };

    // emission probabilities, corresponding to p of rolling 1 thru 6 on fair or loaded die
    double e[6][2] = {
        { log( ((double) 1)/6),  log(0.1) },
        { log( ((double) 1)/6),  log(0.1) },
        { log( ((double) 1)/6),  log(0.1) },
        { log( ((double) 1)/6),  log(0.1) },
        { log( ((double) 1)/6),  log(0.1) },
        { log( ((double) 1)/6),  log(0.5) },
    };

    // allocate rest of memory and error handle
    int *path = calloc(n, sizeof(double));
    double **vprob = calloc(n, sizeof(double *));
    double **ptr = calloc(n, sizeof(double *));
    double **pi = calloc(n, sizeof(double *));

    if( !path || !vprob || !ptr || !pi )
        {
            printf("Not enough memory.");
            return 1;
        }

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        vprob[i] = calloc(n, sizeof(double));
        ptr[i] = calloc(n, sizeof(double));
        pi[i] = calloc(n, sizeof(double));

        if( !vprob[i] || !ptr[i] || !pi[i] )
        {
            printf("Not enough memory.");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    // initialize vprob array; assumed starting state is state F
    vprob[0][0] = 1;
    vprob[1][0] = 0;
    double row0;
    double row1;

    // viterbi algorithm in log space to avoid underflow
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            row0 = (vprob[0][i - 1] + a[0][j]);
            row1 = (vprob[1][i - 1] + a[1][j]);

            vprob[j][i] = e[seq[i]][j] + max( row0, row1 );
            ptr[j][i] = argmax( row0, row1 );
            pi[j][i] = max( row0 , row1 );
        }
    }
    free(seq);

    // traceback to find most likely path
    path[n - 1] = argmax( pi[0][n - 1], pi[1][n - 1] );
    for (int i = n - 2; i > 0; i--)
    {
        path[i] = ptr[path[i + 1]][i + 1];
    }

    // free remaining memory
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        free(vprob[i]);
        free(ptr[i]);
        free(pi[i]);
    }
    free(vprob);
    free(ptr);
    free(pi);

    // print viterbi result
    printf("Viterbi output:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {   
        if (i % 60 == 0 && i != 0)
        {
            printf("\n");
        }

        if (path[i] == 0)
        {
            printf("F");
        }
        if (path[i] == 1)
        {
            printf("L");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    free(path);
    return 0;
}


double max (double a, double b)
{
    if (a > b)
    {
        return a;
    }
    else if (a < b)
    {
    return b;
    }
    // if equal, returns arbitrary argument for specific use in this algorithm
    return b;
}

int argmax (double row0, double row1)
{
    if (row0 > row1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (row0 < row1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return row1;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you are right that you rediscovered the [megamoth](https://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/), and it should be divided into easier to understand and maybe reusable parts.

But let's first look at your 2 functions, which are both unneccessarily long and verbose.

1. If you just used `else` instead of `else if` you could subsume the third case (equality) with one of the other two.
2. There is such a thing called the conditional operator, C's only ternary operator, for selecting one of two values.
3. It looks like `argmax()` should return `1` in the equal case, instead of converting the first floating-point argument to integer, parallel to `max()`.

That gives you:

```
double max(double a, double b)
{
    return a > b ? a : b;
}

int argmax(double a, double b)
{
    return a > b ? 0 : 1;
}
```

4. You really should restrict yourself to some reasonable line-length like 79, horizontal scrolling is absolute murder.
   To that end, know that two string-literals put next to each other will be fused by the compiler:

   ```
   strcmp("a" "b", "ab") == 0
   ```
5. Many of your comments restate the obvious. Others can be made superfluous by extracting a properly named function.
   Candidates are `read_sequencefile()`, `read_and_echo_statefile()`, `do_analysis` and `print_result`.
6. There's a standard way to denote optional arguments in a usage-message: square brackets.
7. There's no need to hardcode your executables filename, look at `argv[0]`.
8. If you use `calloc` you should actually benefit from getting the returned memory zeroed. Otherwise it's just useless makework.
9. Try to minimize the scope of your variables. While the compiler can be expected to defer reservation and initialization and bring forward oblivion, that doesn't help you. The less there is to keep track of, the better.
10. `seq = realloc(seq, memsize * sizeof(int));` is not an error because you immediately exit the program. Otherwise, it would be a memory-leak.
11. Allocate memory when you need it, not if you might need it later.
12. Errors should go to `stderr`, and all output should end with a newline.
13. If you only want to output a single `char`, consider using `putc`.
14. You can use `sizeof` with expressions and types. Try to avoid the latter as it forces you to repeat your types.
15. You should check whether your State file is corrupted.
16. Anyway, did you ever want to do something with the State file?
17. If you want to select something with an index and your indices are dense, consider using an array:

    ```
    putc("FL"[path[i]], stdout);
    // Equivalent if path[i] in 0, 1
    if (path[i] == 0)
    {
        printf("F");
    }
    if (path[i] == 1)
    {
        printf("L");
    }
    ```
18. Instead of casting an integer-constant to `double`, consider simply making it a `double`-constant: `1.`
19. If you allocate and deallocate multiple pieces at the same times, consider coalescing them to only bother the allocator once.
20. Only the first two elements of `vprob`, `ptr` and `pi` are ever used. Don't allocate more, and allocate such small arrays on the stack.
21. Mark anything which shall not be modified `const`. That frees everyone of the fear of missing a change, and lets the compiler enforce it.
22. `return 0;` is implied for `main` since C99.
23. `EXIT_SUCCESS` resp. `0` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are the only standardized exit-codes.
24. Consider making all functions only used in the local file local with `static`. Doing so encourages inlining and avoids emitting a symbol for the linker.

Refactored program:

```
/**
 * Implementation of the viterbi algorithm for estimating the states of a
 * Hidden Markov Model given at least a sequence text file.
 * Program automatically determines n value from sequence file and assumes that
 * state file has same n value.
 * 
 * Program follows example from Durbin et. al.'s "The occasionally dishonest
 * casino, part 1." on p. 54 of Biological Sequence Analyis (2002), with
 * solution and viterbi output given on p. 57. The two states, F and L,
 * correspond to a "Fair" or a "Loaded" die.
 * 
 * free .pdf of Durbin at:
 * http://dnapunctuation.org/~poptsova/course/Durbin-Et-Al-Biological-Sequence-Analysis-CUP-2002-No-OCR.pdf
 * 
 * Optional argument to read in file of known states for comparison with
 * algorithm's output.
 * Sequence file and state files are is assumed to be one entry per line (see
 * .txt files for example).
 * 
 * Usage: ./viterbi my_sequence_file.txt my_state_file.txt
 * my_sequence_file.txt = sequence file (required)
 * my_state_file.txt = state file (optional)
 *
**/


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>

static double max(double a, double b)
{
    return a > b ? a : b;
}

static int argmax(double a, double b)
{
    return a > b ? 0 : 1;
}

static int read_sequencefile(const char filename[], int** sequence)
{
    assert(sequence);
    FILE* file = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (!file) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid sequence file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int size = 0;
    int* seq = 0;

    for(int num, capacity = 0; fscanf(file, "%i", &num) == 1; ) {
        if(size == capacity) {
            capacity += 100;
            seq = realloc(seq, capacity * sizeof *seq);
            if(!seq) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory.\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
        seq[size++] = num;
    }
    if(!feof(file)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Sequence file contains garbage.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fclose(file);
    *sequence = seq;
    return size;
}

static void read_and_echo_statefile(const char filename[], int n)
{
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[2], "r");
    if (!file) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid state file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char* state = malloc(n * sizeof *state);
    if(n && !state) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("State solution:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        char ch;
        if(fscanf(file, " %c ", &ch) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "State file too small.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        state[i] = ch;

        if (i % 60 == 0 && i != 0)
            putc('\n', stdout);
        putc(state[i], stdout);
    }
    if(!feof(file)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "State file too large.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    free(state);
    fclose(file);
    printf("\n\n");
}

static int* do_analysis(const int seq[], int n)
{
    // state transition matrix in log space
    const double a[2][2] = {
        { log(0.95),  log(0.05) },
        { log(0.1),  log(0.9) }
    };

    // emission probabilities, corresponding to probability of rolling 1
    // through 6 on fair or loaded die
    const double e[6][2] = {
        { log( 1. / 6),  log(0.1) },
        { log( 1. / 6),  log(0.1) },
        { log( 1. / 6),  log(0.1) },
        { log( 1. / 6),  log(0.1) },
        { log( 1. / 6),  log(0.1) },
        { log( 1. / 6),  log(0.5) },
    };

    int *path = malloc(n * sizeof *path);
    *path = 0;
    double* vprob[2] = { calloc(3 * 2 * n, sizeof **vprob), NULL };
    if(n && (!path || ! vprob[0])) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    vprob[1] = vprob[0] + n;
    double* ptr[2] = { vprob[1] + n, vprob[1] + 2 * n };
    double* pi[2] = { ptr[1] + n, ptr[1] + 2 * n };

    // initialize vprob array; assumed starting state is state F
    vprob[0][0] = 1;
    vprob[1][0] = 0;

    // viterbi algorithm in log space to avoid underflow
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            double row0 = (vprob[0][i - 1] + a[0][j]);
            double row1 = (vprob[1][i - 1] + a[1][j]);

            vprob[j][i] = e[seq[i]][j] + max( row0, row1 );
            ptr[j][i] = argmax( row0, row1 );
            pi[j][i] = max( row0 , row1 );
        }
    }

    // traceback to find most likely path
    path[n - 1] = argmax( pi[0][n - 1], pi[1][n - 1] );
    for (int i = n - 2; i > 0; i--)
        path[i] = ptr[path[i + 1]][i + 1];

    free(vprob[0]);
    return path;
}

static void print_result(const int path[], int n)
{
    printf("Viterbi output:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {   
        if (i % 60 == 0 && i != 0)
            putc('\n', stdout);
        putc("FL"[path[i]], stdout);
    }
    putc('\n', stdout);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    if (argc != 2 && argc != 3) {
        printf("Usage: %s sequence_file.txt [state_file.txt]\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int* seq;
    int n = read_sequencefile(argv[1], &seq);

    if(argv[2])
        read_and_echo_statefile(argv[2], n);

    int* path = do_analysis(seq, n);
    free(seq);

    print_result(path, n);
    free(path);
}
```

I didn't test *all* occurrences of `calloc` whether `malloc` is sufficient.
The only line 80 or bigger contains the URL, because you just don't break URLs if possible.

Comment: A lot of great stuff to sift through here between your post and the one below. Thanks so much.

Comment: Very complete review! Just a very small spot about another latent error: you assign to `int*` the memory allocated for `sizeof(double)`. I'm not aware of any system where `sizeof(int) > sizeof(double)` but in that case it will fail when you deference that pointer.

Comment: Good deep review.  1) `double* vprob[2] = { calloc(3 * 2 * n, sizeof **vprob) };` _looks_ wrong with only 1 initializer.  Suggest `should be `double* vprob[2] = { calloc(3 * 2 * n, sizeof *vprob[0]), NULL };`  2) An empty file will `int n = 0;` and could take the `if` path with `if(!path || ! vprob[0]) {` provide erroneous `"Not enough memory.\n"` message.  3) Per #21, `void print_result(int* path, int n)` --> `void print_result(const int* path, int n)`  4) `putc("FL"[path[i]], stdout);` treads on thin ice.  Perhaps `putc("FL"[1&path[i]], stdout);` or `[(bool)path[i]]` or use `bool* path`

Comment: ...  5) C does not specified "integer-literal" but _integer constant_.  Like-wise for `double literal.  The 2 literals C specifies (string, compound) can have their address taken unlike an integer constant.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Code Review, very nice first question for Code Review!

You're quite correct about the program structure and you may want to do some research on software design principles such as the Single Responsibility Principle, the [Don't Repeat Yourself Principle (DRY code)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), the [Keep It Simple KIS(S)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) principle and [Demeter's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

**What is the State File For?**

Currently the program is reading the state information from the file, but the state information is never used, the state array is thrown away after it is input. This could almost be considered a bug or broken code.

**Use stderr to Report Errors**

When C was first developed the creators created 3 File pointers to use, `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`. The function `printf()` prints to `stdout`, `scanf()` reads from `stdin` and a special file pointer for reporting error messages was created, this is `stderr`. It is better to report errors to stderr than stdout because redirecting file output by `progname arguments > outfile` does not redirect stderr. It is possible to redirect stderr to a file as well using `progname arguments >& outfile` (Unix and Linux).

To print errors to `stderr`:

```
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR MESSAGE");
```

**Reduce Complexity, Follow SRP**

The [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) states that every module or class should have responsibility over a single part of the functionality provided by the software, and that responsibility should be entirely encapsulated by the class. All its services should be narrowly aligned with that responsibility.

```
Robert C. Martin expresses the principle as follows:
    `A class should have only one reason to change.`
```

While this is primarily targeted at classes in object oriented languages it applies to functions and
subroutines in procedural languages like C as well.

The main function could be broken up into at least 4 functions:

```
int* resize_seq(int* seq, int* memsize);
int* process_sequence_input_file(/* in variable */ char* input_file, /* out variables */ int* out_n)
char* process_state_file(char* statefilename, int n);
int execute_biological_sequence_analysis(int *seq, int sequence_size, char *state)
```

The function execute_biological_sequence_analysis() can be broken up into multiple functions as well.

Here is an example of what the program might look like following the Single Responsibility Principle.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define SEQUENCE_MEMORY_ALLOCATION_SIZE    100
#define DIE_FACE_COUNT  6

double max (double a, double b)
{
    if (a > b)
    {
        return a;
    }
    else if (a < b)
    {
        return b;
    }
    // if equal, returns arbitrary argument for specific use in this algorithm
    return b;
}

double argmax (double row0, double row1)
{
    if (row0 > row1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (row0 < row1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return row1;
}

int* resize_seq(int* seq, int* memsize)
{
    *memsize += SEQUENCE_MEMORY_ALLOCATION_SIZE;
    seq = realloc(seq, *memsize * sizeof(int));
    if(!seq)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory to allocate or reallocate seq.");
    }
    return seq;
}

int* process_sequence_input_file(/* in variable */ char* input_file, /* out variables */ int* out_n)
{
    int memsize = SEQUENCE_MEMORY_ALLOCATION_SIZE;
    int n = 0;
    int num;

    int *seq = calloc(memsize, sizeof(int));
    if (!seq)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    // open sequence file and store in array. Dynamically allocate memory and automatically detect sequence n value
    FILE *seqf = fopen(input_file, "r");
    if (!seqf)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file %s.\n", input_file);
        free(seq);
        return NULL;
    }

    while(fscanf(seqf, "%i", &num) == 1)
    {
        seq[n] = num - 1;
        n++;

        if (n == memsize)
        {
            if (!(seq = resize_seq(seq, &memsize))) {
                return NULL;
            }
        }

    }
    fclose(seqf);

    *out_n = n;         // return n

    return seq;
}

char* process_state_file(char* statefilename, int n)
{
    FILE *statef = fopen(statefilename, "r");

    if (!statef)
    {
        printf("Invalid state file.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    char *state = calloc(n, sizeof(char));
    if(!state)
    {
        printf("Not enough memory.");
        return NULL;
    }

    char ch;
    printf("State solution:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        fscanf(statef, "%c %*[\r\n]", &ch);
        state[i] = ch;

        if (i % 60 == 0 && i != 0)
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("%c", state[i]);
    }
    fclose(statef);
    printf("\n\n");

    return state;
}

int execute_biological_sequence_analysis(int *seq, int sequence_size, char *state)
{
    int status = EXIT_SUCCESS;

    // state transition matrix in log space
    double a[2][2] = {
        { log(0.95),  log(0.05) },
        { log(0.1),  log(0.9) }
    };

    // emission probabilities, corresponding to p of rolling 1 thru 6 on fair or loaded die
    double e[DIE_FACE_COUNT][2] = {
        { log( ((double) 1)/DIE_FACE_COUNT),  log(0.1) },
        { log( ((double) 1)/DIE_FACE_COUNT),  log(0.1) },
        { log( ((double) 1)/DIE_FACE_COUNT),  log(0.1) },
        { log( ((double) 1)/DIE_FACE_COUNT),  log(0.1) },
        { log( ((double) 1)/DIE_FACE_COUNT),  log(0.1) },
        { log( ((double) 1)/DIE_FACE_COUNT),  log(0.5) },
    };

    // allocate rest of memory and error handle
    int *path = calloc(sequence_size, sizeof(double));
    double **vprob = calloc(sequence_size, sizeof(double *));
    double **ptr = calloc(sequence_size, sizeof(double *));
    double **pi = calloc(sequence_size, sizeof(double *));

    if( !path || !vprob || !ptr || !pi )
    {
        printf("Not enough memory.");
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        vprob[i] = calloc(sequence_size, sizeof(double));
        ptr[i] = calloc(sequence_size, sizeof(double));
        pi[i] = calloc(sequence_size, sizeof(double));

        if( !vprob[i] || !ptr[i] || !pi[i] )
        {
            printf("Not enough memory.");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    // initialize vprob array; assumed starting state is state F
    vprob[0][0] = 1;
    vprob[1][0] = 0;
    double row0;
    double row1;

    // viterbi algorithm in log space to avoid underflow
    for (int i = 1; i < sequence_size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            row0 = (vprob[0][i - 1] + a[0][j]);
            row1 = (vprob[1][i - 1] + a[1][j]);

            vprob[j][i] = e[seq[i]][j] + max( row0, row1 );
            ptr[j][i] = argmax( row0, row1 );
            pi[j][i] = max( row0 , row1 );
        }
    }

    // traceback to find most likely path
    path[sequence_size - 1] = argmax( pi[0][sequence_size - 1], pi[1][sequence_size - 1] );
    for (int i = sequence_size - 2; i > 0; i--)
    {
        path[i] = ptr[path[i + 1]][i + 1];
    }

    // free remaining memory
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        free(vprob[i]);
        free(ptr[i]);
        free(pi[i]);
    }
    free(vprob);
    free(ptr);
    free(pi);

    // print viterbi result
    printf("Viterbi output:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < sequence_size; i++)
    {
        if (i % 60 == 0 && i != 0)
        {
            printf("\n");
        }

        if (path[i] == 0)
        {
            printf("F");
        }
        if (path[i] == 1)
        {
            printf("L");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    free(path);

    return status;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int status = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    // check for correct number of command line args
    if (argc != 2 && argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./viterbi my_sequence_file.txt my_state_file.txt .  Include at least sequence file.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int sequence_size = 0;
    int *seq;

    if (!(seq = process_sequence_input_file(argv[1], &sequence_size)))
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char *state = NULL;
    // if passed as an argument, open the state solution file and print. Assumes n is same as sequence n above
    if(argv[2])
    {
        if (!(state = process_state_file(argv[2], sequence_size)))
        {
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    status = execute_biological_sequence_analysis(seq, sequence_size, state);

    free(seq);
    free(state);

    return status;
}
```

**Use Sybolic Constants Rather than Numeric Constants**

There are a number of numeric constants such as 6, 100, 0.1, 0.5 that could be represented as symbolic constants,
here is an example of two of them

```
#define SEQUENCE_MEMORY_ALLOCATION_SIZE    100
#define DIE_FACE_COUNT  6
```

There are 2 constants defined in stdlib.h and stdlib, these are `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE`. These make `main()` more readable rather than return 0, return [EXIT_SUCCESS or EXIT_FAILURE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/EXIT_status)
from main, this will also allow error handling to be added at some point in the future.

Symbolic constants help programmers in a number of ways:

- They make the code more readable
- They decrease the number of lines that need to be changed in an edit, this makes changing the code easier in the future.
- When using constants to create the size of arrays, it is much easier to change all the arrays sizes and loop constants at once.

**Variable Names**

Generally the variable names are ok, some might improve with additional length such as changing `seq`
to `sequence`. One variable should probably be renamed from `n` to `sequence_size since it is used in
much of the program.

**Testing the Return of Allocation**

The code contains all the necessary testing to see if `calloc()` returns a value or not, but it would be
better if each call to `calloc()` was immediately tested rather than what the following code does:

```
    // allocate rest of memory and error handle
    int *path = calloc(sequence_size, sizeof(double));
    double **vprob = calloc(sequence_size, sizeof(double *));
    double **ptr = calloc(sequence_size, sizeof(double *));
    double **pi = calloc(sequence_size, sizeof(double *));

    if( !path || !vprob || !ptr || !pi )
    {
        printf("Not enough memory.");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        vprob[i] = calloc(sequence_size, sizeof(double));
        ptr[i] = calloc(sequence_size, sizeof(double));
        pi[i] = calloc(sequence_size, sizeof(double));

        if( !vprob[i] || !ptr[i] || !pi[i] )
        {
            printf("Not enough memory.");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
```

One possible solution would be to create a function that calls `calloc()` and then tests the return value, this would apply the DRY principle (Don't Repeat Yourself).

```
double** calloc_with_test_and_error_message(int memsize, char *arrayName)
{
    double** arrayofdoublepointers = calloc(1, memsize);
    if (!arrayofdoublepointers)
    {
         fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: calloc failed to create the array of double pointers %s\n", arrayName);
    }
    return arrayofdoublepointers;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for such a comprehensive reply, a lot of goof stuff for me to check out here.

Comment: `int argmax (double row0, double row1)
{ ... return row1; }`  looks wrong.  Returning a `double` as an `int`?

Comment: `int* process_sequence_input_file(/* in variable */ char* input_file, ...` is sufficient as `int* process_sequence_input_file(const char* input_file, ...` as the `const` enforces the "in-ness" of `input_file`.

`

Comment: `if(!state)
    {
        printf("Not enough memory.");` is not necessarily true if `n==0`.  Could use `if(!state && n)...`.  IMO, better for `n` to be `size_t` than `int`, yet that reflects back on much of OP code.

Comment: Using `ptr = alloc(sizeof *ptr * n)` model would have not caused the coding oops in `int *path = calloc(sequence_size, sizeof(double));`.  Recommend `int *path = calloc(sequence_size, sizeof *path);`

Comment: @chux The program example did not correct the issues in the OP's code. That may have been a mistake on my part, but I wanted the OP to be able to compare apples to apples. I do thank you for the corrections.

Comment: @pacmaninbw True about editing another's code - one touches a small portion and others credit/blame you for the whole thing.

Answer (score 2):

#### Too large allocations

I noticed that you allocated several arrays of length `n` here:

> ```
> // allocate rest of memory and error handle
> int *path = calloc(n, sizeof(double));
> double **vprob = calloc(n, sizeof(double *));
> double **ptr = calloc(n, sizeof(double *));
> double **pi = calloc(n, sizeof(double *));
>
> if( !path || !vprob || !ptr || !pi )
>     {
>         printf("Not enough memory.");
>         return 1;
>     }
> ```

Problem number one is that for `path` you allocated space for `n` doubles instead of `n` ints (typo most likely).  To avoid this problem you should use the variable itself in the `sizeof()` instead of hardcoding a type.

Problem number two is that of these 4 arrays, only `path` needed to be of size `n`.  The other three are only supposed to be size 2.  So really, you don't even need to allocate those, you could just do this:

```
// allocate rest of memory and error handle
int    *path    = calloc(n, sizeof(*path));
double *vrob[2] = {0};
double *ptr [2] = {0};
double *pi  [2] = {0};

if( !path )
{
    printf("Not enough memory.");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

#### Potential buffer overflow

Your `argmax()` function returns `row1` when `row0 == row1`, but I think it is supposed to return 1 instead.  Later on, the result of `argmax()` is used as an index into the `ptr[]` array, which only has two entries.  So if `row0` and `row1` were both 5, for example, you would get a buffer overflow later on.

Comment: Idea: As `vrob[2]` is fixed at 2, `double *vrob[2] = {NULL, NULL};` adds clarity.  `if( !path )`has same corner case issue when `n==0` in providing [wrong message](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/163674/viterbi-algorithm-implementation-in-c#comment311331_163693).

Answer (score 2):

OP's code is largely well reviewed.  Just adding a bit

---

The `"%*[\r\n]"` in `fscanf(statef, "%c %*[\r\n]", &ch);` serves no purpose.

The `" "` in `fscanf()` format consumes any 0 or more white-space characters including `\r` and `\n`.  So these is nothing left to consume by `"%*[\r\n]"`.

Further, if the file begins with a white space like `'\n'`, that character will get saved in `ch`.  Not likely code's intent.

If there is not enough data, code could be reading uninitialized data with `state[i] = ch;`, which is *undefined behavior* (UB).

Consider validating `fscanf()` results before using `ch` by checking, at least, the return value.

```
    char ch;
    printf("State solution:\n");
    fflush(stdout);  // Insure output is seen 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // skip white-spaces 
        //                  v
        if (fscanf(statef, " %c", &ch) != 1) {
          Handle_Scant_Input();
        }
        state[i] = ch;
        ...
```